# Сделать эффект перелистывания страниц как в книге

Tags: java, android

Интересует программная реализация эффекта перелистывания страниц, например как здесь[image: перелистывание]

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вот это - https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl